# Previous/Next links based on model's function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I display previous/next links according to `vehicle.vehicle_status`

In my show view:

```
- if @vehicle.previous
  = link_to "< Previous", @vehicle.previous
- if @vehicle.next
  = link_to "Next >", @vehicle.next
```

In my model:

```
def previous
  ?
end

def next
  ?
end
```

vehicles/index.html.haml view:

```
- @vehicles.each do |vehicle|
  %tr
    %td.dashbox{:class => vehicle.vehicle_status, :style =>'width:18px;', :onclick=>"top.location=#{vehicle_url(vehicle)}"}
```

vehicle_status in model:

```
def vehicle_status
  if self.maintenance_status=='c1' or self.fuel_efficiency_status=='c1' or self.system_status=='c1'
  'c1'
  elsif self.maintenance_status=='c2' or self.fuel_efficiency_status=='c2' or self.system_status=='c2'
  'c2'
  elsif self.maintenance_status=='c4' or self.fuel_efficiency_status=='c4' or self.system_status=='c4'
  'c4'
  else
  'c3'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :previous, lambda { |vehicle| 
  where("vehicles.vehicle_status < ?", vehicle.vehicle_status).
    order(:vehicle_status).reverse
}

scope :next, lambda { |vehicle|
  where("vehicles.vehicle_status > ?", vehicle.vehicle_status).
    order(:vehicle_status)
}

def previous
  @previous ||= Vehicle.previous(self).first
end

def next
  @next ||= Vehicle.next(self).first
end
```

In light of the fact that `vehicle_status` is a calculation and not a static field, and that there are other factors involved in the sorting, you can modify the scopes to look like this (using a helper method for the CASE string):

```
def self.vehicle_status_sql
  <<-SQL
    CASE 
      WHEN 'c1' IN (maintentance_status, fuel_efficiency_status, system_status) THEN 'c1'
      WHEN 'c2' IN (maintentance_status, fuel_efficiency_status, system_status) THEN 'c2'
      WHEN 'c4' IN (maintentance_status, fuel_efficiency_status, system_status) THEN 'c4'
      ELSE 'c3'
    END
  SQL
end

scope :previous, lambda { |vehicle| 
  where("#{vehicle_status_sql} < :status OR (#{vehicle_status_sql} = :status AND (vehicles.odometer < :odometer OR (vehicles.odometer = :odometer AND vehicles.id < :id)))", 
    status: vehicle.vehicle_status, odometer: vehicle.odometer, id: vehicle.id).
  order("#{vehicle_status_sql} DESC, vehicles.odometer DESC")
}

scope :next, lambda { |vehicle| 
  where("#{vehicle_status_sql} > :status OR ((#{vehicle_status_sql} = :status AND (vehicles.odometer > :odometer OR (vehicles.odometer = :odometer AND vehicles.id > :id)))",
    status: vehicle.vehicle_status, odometer: vehicle.odometer, id: vehicle.id).
  order("#{vehicle_status_sql}, vehicles.odometer)
}
```

Comment: My bad again, use `reverse` - not `desc`. Updated.

Comment: `vehicle_url(vehicle)` isn't doing what you think it is...  Change that to `url_for(vehicle)`.  And you're kidding me about that case statement, right?  Please normalize your schema to avoid the pain involved with using a database CASE statement (especially in ActiveRecord).

Comment: Oh, is that what it's supposed to do? :)  I thought the current behavior is what you wanted.  So within a single vehicle_status what sort order should be used to determine the vehicles' sequence?

Comment: Ok, updated to sort by status, then odometer, then id.  Id is needed to force a sort order where the status and odometer of 2 vehicles match.

Comment: thanks, my boss moved vehicle_status to the database as per your request. if you could please update your code to reflect this and delete all the comments to make this post look nice rather than messy... thanks..